# How to access array from different class in objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class

I know that this question has been asked several times already, but after extensive search, none of them work for me so far. I want to avoid using a singleton if possible. Sorry if this is considered a repeat question.

I have a MutableArray with 5 objects in my ViewController.m file called storyList. I want to be able to access this storyList array in my DetailViewController.m file.

One method I have tried is:
(storyListArrayinDetail is a new array in detailviewcontroller, storyList is the array with 5 objects from ViewController.h)
In ViewController.h

```
DetailViewController *controller;
```

In ViewController.m

```
 controller = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
 controller.storyListArrayinDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];       
 controller.storyListArrayinDetail = storyList;
```

When I log controller.storyListArrayinDetail in ViewController.m, I get the correct array of 5 objects. However, when I log storyListArrayinDetail in DetailViewController.m, I get nothing.

Comment: Because you have allocated a new, completely separated DetailViewController that has nothing to do with the one that adds the 5 items to the array.

Comment: [Check this out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science))

Comment: I need additional information: how to you instantiate the DetailViewController and ViewController? Do you have a pointer to them in your app delegate?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, I am using storyboard

Comment: Are you using a segue to trigger the loading of the `DetailViewController`?

Comment: @robmayoff I am loading a tableView and then segue for loading a DetailViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the method `(id)init` on DetailViewController.m ,and initialize storyListArrayinDetail here. 
Then, whenever initializing a DetailViewController you will be initializing storyListArrayinDetail as well. So, for sending your storyList just use your code as this:

```
controller = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
controller.storyListArrayinDetail = storyList;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: How do I use the array `controller.storyListArrayinDetail` in DetailViewController? There is no controller defined in detailViewController

Comment: This is what I meant, on `DetailViewController.m` override init method and initialize `storyListArrayinDetail` like this:
 `- (id)init {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
          storyListArrayinDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  
       }  
       return self;
   }`
No need to use `controller`, because you are inside `DetailViewController` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new init method in your DetailViewController and pass in the array when you initialize it.

*//Assuming DetailViewController is in fact a UIViewController, not sure from init method in OP.*

DetailedViewController.h

```
@interface DetailedViewController : UIViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withDataArray:(NSArray*)dataArray;
@end
```

DetailedViewController.m

```
@interface DetailedViewController () {
   NSArray *myDataArray;
}

@end

@implementation DetailedViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withDataArray:(NSArray*)dataArray
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
            myDataArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:dataArray];
        }
        return self;
    }

...
```

Then in DetailedViewController you can use `myDataArray`. Hope that helps.

EDIT: To include Hot_Licks suggestion:

DetailedViewController.h

```
@interface DetailedViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, assign)NSArray *myDataArray;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
DetailedViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
[controller setMyDataArray:xyArray];
```

Comment: Or you can add a property to the controller and set it with the array address after the controller is created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I think it should work, but when I put `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withDataArray:(NSArray*)dataArray;` in `DetailViewController.h`, I get 2 errors: `Expected member name or '; ' after declaration specifiers` and `Type name requires a specifier or qualifier`

Comment: Is you DetailViewController a UIViewController? Or a UIView?